# How can I write the left and right sides of the equation in different sizes?

Tags: discussion, support, mathjax

I hope I'm at the right place to write my question.Because the mathjax tag exists at both [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com)and [tex.stackexchange.com](https://tex.stackexchange.com).

I want to write this equation (This is just an example)

$$G(x_1,x_2,x_3,\cdots, x_n):=A_1(x_1)+A_2(x_2)+ A_3(x_3)+\cdots+A_n(x_n)$$

in MathJax but my MathJax syntax doesn't work.

I want to write the left side of equation with larger syntax and the right of side with normal syntax. But, my MathJax syntax doesn`t work.
I tried:

```
\mathlarger {G(x_1,x_2,x_3,\cdots, x_n)}:=A_1(x_1)+A_2(x_2)+ A_3(x_3)+cdots+A_n(x_n)

\bigletter {G(x_1,x_2,x_3,\cdots, x_n)}:=A_1(x_1)+A_2(x_2)+ A_3(x_3)+cdots+A_n(x_n)

\mathlarger {G(x_1,x_2,x_3,\cdots, x_n)}:=A_1(x_1)+A_2(x_2)+ A_3(x_3)+cdots+A_n(x_n)
```

But, `\mathlarger{G}`, `\bigletter {G}` and `\ensuremath {G}` [doesn't work](https://arachnoid.com/latex/?equ=%0A%5Censuremath%20%7BG%7D%0A%0A%5Cmathlarger%7BG%7D%0A%0A%5Cbigletter%7BG%7D).

```
\Large {G(x_1,x_2,x_3,\cdots, x_n)}=A_1(x_1)+A_2(x_2)+ A_3(x_3)+cdots+A_n(x_n)

\huge {G(x_1,x_2,x_3,\cdots, x_n)}=A_1(x_1)+A_2(x_2)+ A_3(x_3)+cdots+A_n(x_n)
```

In the last line I use `\Large` and `\huge` change all equations size. So, I have no idea, what can I do.

Comment: Limit the scope of `\Large`, e.g. `{\Large G(x_1,\dotsc, x_n)} = A_1(x_1)` produces ${\Large G(x_1,\dotsc, x_n)} = A_1(x_1)$. (And wow, that looks ugly. At most use `\large`.)

Comment: @DanielFischer Ohh..Finally..Thank you very much..!and I want to ask is https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/ right place for such questions?

Comment: Questions about how to do stuff in MathJax are somewhat on topic here (take a look at the questions tagged [tag:mathjax]). But I think such questions often would be better suited for [tex.se] (however, I don't really know the scope of the mathjax tag there).

Comment: @DanielFischer  The users of https://tex.stackexchange.com directed me to https://stackoverflow.com. Because MathJax is off topic. Users of https://stackoverflow.com have stated that this is a much more wrong place. I found the last address with my own head :) I see that, there were only 2 parenthesis errors in my syntax

Comment: Ah, well. You can however always ask how to do stuff in $\LaTeX$ over there (after looking for duplicates first), and then check whether it also works in MathJax.

Comment: @DanielFischer I've spent almost $2$ hours for $2$ parenthesis errors... Thank you for to solve the problem and for further information.

Comment: @DanielFischer by the way can I ask why `\mathlarger` and `\bigletter` doesnt work in mathjax?

Comment: I don't know `\mathlarger` or `\bigletter`. I'd guess that either MathJax doesn't know them at all, or you must `\require` some package that provides them.

Comment: @DanielFischer I found it https://tex.stackexchange.com  while looking for a solution to my question. Well. I understood.Thanks again!

Comment: I suppose that MathJax is off-topic at the TeX StackExchange because that is about TeX for publication, and they would be overwhelmed with MathJax questions if it were on-topic (or so I assume).  So the question of why `mathlarger` and other commands aren't implemented in MathJax is off-topic, but the similar question of which packages they require would be on-topic.  The question of why `large` and `huge` didn't do what you expected, would also be on-topic, although you'd probably first want to check (perhaps at https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php) that it's not a MathJax error.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The size directives `\large` etc. are not commands taking arguments. Their effect lasts until the scope<sup>(1)</sup> in which they were issued ends. The same holds for style selectors like `\displaystyle`, `\scriptscriptstyle` and so on. Thus wrapping `G(x_1, \dotsc, x_n)` in braces doesn't make it an argument to `\large`, it just makes the expression an ordinary maths atom (which can be important for correct spacing). To end the effect of the size directive before the end of the equation, you need to create a new scope (typically via braces, but beginning a new environment (e.g. `cases`) and issuing the directive there is also possible).

```
{\large G(x_1,x_2,x_3,\cdots, x_n)} := A_1(x_1)+A_2(x_2)+ A_3(x_3)+\cdots+A_n(x_n)
```

produces
$${\large G(x_1,x_2,x_3,\cdots, x_n)} := A_1(x_1)+A_2(x_2)+ A_3(x_3)+\cdots+A_n(x_n)$$

---

<sup>(1)</sup> I'm not a $\TeX$ expert, I may not be using the official terminology.

Comment: LaTeX wikibook suggest it's a switch. okay maybe not quite, but close.